# find each student's highest score

Tags: sql

I have this table contains student id and their score for each

```
|student id  |score|
|    aac     |  3  |
|    aaa     |  6  |
|    aac     |  5  |
|    aaa     |  7  |
|    aad     |  3  |
```

I want to find the highest score for each student. How do I do it?

*I tried going through every student ID on the list but it is not efficient.*

Comment: This is quite easy actually. The **"highest score"** (or "greatest score" or "maximum score" etc.) is `MAX(score)`. **"for each student"** (or "per student") translates to `GROUP BY student`. Look out for such keywords in the tasks and it will be easy to get to a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the exact table you gave, a simple group by query should work:

```
SELECT student_id, MAX(score) AS max_score
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY student_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `row_number`

```
select
  student_id,
  score
from
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by student_id order by score desc) as rn
  from yourTable
) subq
where rn = 1
```